# Wordpress php if else help. Show php and html in the echo

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I need help in getting this if else statement working. I have the HTML showing up on the website but I also need the php working too. I do not know a way around doing an echo inside of another echo (which is frowned upon). Any suggestions would help!

```
code
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {echo "
<div id='fixedbar'>
<div id='boxfloat'>
<div id='header'>
<img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/punchtab-static/nd/images/favicon.ico' id='favicon'       border='0' onerror='imageNotFound(this, '//s3.amazonaws.com/punchtab-  static/nd/images/bar/shield.png')' onload='imageFound(this)' style='visibility: visible;'>
</div>
<p>
Rewards
<div id='points'>
<div id='user'>
echo 'cosmo_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID') , 30 )'; ?>
</div>
echo cp_displayPoints($user->ID)'; pts
</div>
<div id='more'>
<a href='/leaderboard'>
<img border='0' src='http://expertcamo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/icon-leaderboard.png' id='leaderboard' alt='Leaderboard' title='Expert Camo Points Leaderboard'</a>

<a href='/catalog'>
<img border='0' src='http://expertcamo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/icon-trophy.png' id='catalog' alt='Catalog' title='Rewards Catalog'</a>

</div>
</p>
<div id='copyright'><a href='/'>
Expert Camo &copy; echo 'date('Y')';</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
";} else { echo "
<div id='fixedbar'>
<div id='boxfloat'>

</div>
</div>
";}
?>
```

Comment: It would help if you specified exactly what is happening and what you would like to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but based on what you had should work:

```
    <?php
if(is_user_logged_in()){
               echo "
                <div id='fixedbar'>
                <div id='boxfloat'>
                <div id='header'>
                <img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/punchtab-static/nd/images/favicon.ico' id='favicon'           border='0' onerror='imageNotFound(this, '//s3.amazonaws.com/punchtab-      static/nd/images/bar/shield.png')' onload='imageFound(this)' style='visibility: visible;'>
                </div>
                <p>
                Rewards
                <div id='points'>
                <div id='user'>";
                echo cosmo_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID') , 30 );
                echo "</div>";

                echo cp_displayPoints($user->ID) . 'pts';


                echo "</div>
                <div id='more'>
                <a href='/leaderboard'>
                <img border='0' src='http://expertcamo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/icon-leaderboard.png' id='leaderboard' alt='Leaderboard' title='Expert Camo Points Leaderboard'</a>

                <a href='/catalog'>
                <img border='0' src='http://expertcamo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/icon-trophy.png' id='catalog' alt='Catalog' title='Rewards Catalog'</a>

                </div>
                </p>
                <div id='copyright'><a href='/'>Expert Camo &copy; ";

                echo date('Y');

                echo "</a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>";

        }
            else{

                    echo "<div id='fixedbar'>
                            <div id='boxfloat'>
                            </div>
                            </div>";

            }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you MrTechie! That worked perfectly. What exactly did you do so I can know for future references? Thanks again.

Comment: @MarcusGollahon Study the code. I have given you the answer already. Study the code to see what's different so you will learn, and understand why.

Answer (score -1):

I would rather you load a template instead of echoing all that html, however, you can call functions within your echo by exiting out of the quotes like so

```
<?php echo 'Some text ... ' . cosmo_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID'), 30) . ' and some more text'; ?>
```

Comment: Ok so I can exit out of the echo quotes and the rest will run?